# How to set mesos master offer_timeout config in minimesos

Tags: mesos, minimesos

I'm using minimesos to create mesos for an integration test. On the documentation for mesos I've found the config flag "offer_timeout" which would allow you to set the time after which a resource offer is cancelled, if there is no response to it. Does anyone know how/if it is possible to set this configuration variable using minimesos?

Additionally, the docs are pretty unhelpful about units. Anyone have a suggestion for what the value is actually meant to be? The docs for the flag are below.

> --offer_timeout=VALUE - Duration of time before an offer is rescinded from a framework. This helps fairness when running frameworks that hold on to offers, or frameworks that accidentally drop offers. If not set, offers do not timeout.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if is the same with minimesos, but in Mesos you can set the time using different units.  I was playing with this flag and got the following error message:

Failed to load flag 'offer_timeout': Failed to load value '2s': Unknown duration unit 's'; supported units are 'ns', 'us', 'ms', 'secs', 'mins', 'hrs', 'days', and 'weeks'

If you want to set the time to 2 secnds then either use --offer_timeout=2secs or create a file /etc/mesos-master/offer_timeout and the content inside is just 2secs